# Converting time string text to hours and minutes in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a time string in a text-formatted cell that looks like this: "102:16:47.04". How can I convert it to time string like this: "102:16" ?

Comment: Does it make any scene `"102:16:47.04" `,, what you have entered beyond the `24 Hrs Clock`!! Edit the Time value otherwise this may attract Down Vote to Close the post.

Comment: @RajeshS As a time lapse, it makes perfect sense: 102 hours, 16 minutes, 47 seconds, and 40 milliseconds.

Comment: @jonsca,, but no where OP has mentioned about the Time Laps,, and in what regard!!

Comment: @RajeshS Why does it matter, really?  It seems like he just wants to do some basic string processing.  The example could have been anything.  I was curious as to whether there was a need to parse it back into a date and time to truncate it, but even then, it would still work.

Comment: Converting it from a string back to a date yields `1/4/1900 6:16:47 AM` which is a perfectly valid value.  Whether that is applicable to any reasonable situation is immaterial.

Comment: Are your values stored as strings or Excel time values formatted to appear in that format?

Comment: @RajeshS Relax! Odds are, a viewer wouldn’t impulsively downvote, rather ask for more detail in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can just format it:

```
=TEXT(myTimeString,"[hh]:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is in A1, you can get the substring via this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,(FIND(":",A1,FIND(":",A1)+1))-1)
```

Comment: I'm assuming your string is just `102:16:47.04` without the quotes around it.

Comment: Your Formula returns `"102:16`  last ` " ` is missing it should `"102:16"` !!

Comment: @RajeshS As I wrote in my comment immediately above yours, I'm assuming the OP is only processing the content of the string and has delineated it with the quotes.  Please tone it down a bit.

Comment: ,, since the Time is within the Quotes and OP wants to return `"102:16"` then only `LEFT` Function can do it   `=LEFT(A1,7)&"""" ` !!